# Schema Spy unable to find postgresql driver

Tags: java, postgresql, jar, driver, schemaspy

I want to use Schema Spy to generate schema diagrams,

I have specifed the following command

```
java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t pgsql -host 10.100.71.21[:5432] -db mydb -s public -u username -p password -dp postgresql-8.0-312.jdbc3.jar -o output/
```

I have the postgresql driver jar file in the same directory as schema spy jar file. But it gives the following error

```
[schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar]/net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/pgsql.properties
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver

Failed to load driver 'org.postgresql.Driver'from: [file:/home/panx/postgresql-8.0- 312.jdbc3.jar]
This entry doesn't point to a valid file/directory: [/whereever/postgresql-8.0-312.jdbc3.jar]

Use the -dp option to specify the location of the database
 drivers for your database (usually in a .jar or .zip/.Z).
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Pankaj

Comment: Is there any configuration file which has this line /whereever/postgresql-8.0-312.jdbc3.jar . Maybe it is something you have to edit.

Comment: @mbaydar The -dp configuration is used to specify path to driver file which is what I am doing

Comment: Can you add your configuration file ?

Comment: The configuration file is actually embedded in SchemaSpy.jar. I cant modify it by I can override it by using "-dp" option.

Comment: Please do **not** use that out-dated and obsolete driver. Use a  current driver (9.0 or 9.1). If your driver is actually matching your PostgreSQL version you should immediately update to a supported and current version.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the problem is you didn't add the classpath to the driver. You have to add your classpath like this

```
java -jar schemaSpy_5.0.0.jar -t pgsql -host 10.100.71.21[:5432] -db mydb -s public -u username -p password -dp /home/panx/postgresql-8.0-312.jdbc3.jar -o output/
```

If it does not work you can download the source code of this project. In the project there is pgsql.properties file in dbTypes folder. You can change it with your classpath and I think this solves your problem.

Comment: Downloading the source code was the only option left with me. And it worked :)

Comment: I did not know where to look for the jdbc3 driver path on my computer so I downloaded it from this page: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the driver from [here](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download/).
2. Specify the path to the driver file with `-dp`.

   For example:

   ```
   java -jar schemaSpy.jar   \
     -t pgsql11              \
     -host <host>:<port>     \
     -db <database_name>     \
     -s <schema_name>        \
     -u <database_user>      \
     -p  <password>          \
     -o <output_directory>   \
     -dp <path_to_downloaded_driver>
   ```

   One-liner on Windows:

   ```
   java -jar schemaSpy.jar  -t pgsql -host localhost:5432 -db _dbname_ -s _schena_name_ -u postgres -p  -o D:\RVA\postgreSQL\  -dp "D:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\pgJDBC\postgresql-42.2.5.jar"
   ```

---

NOTE: There are two possible values for database type's value (`-t`) when it comes to PostgreSQL:

```
$ schemaspy --dbhelp
...
INFO  - PostgreSQL Before Version 11 (-t pgsql)
INFO  -    -host        host of database, may contain port
INFO  -    -port        optional port if not default
INFO  -    -db          database name
INFO  - PostgreSQL On Or After Version 11 (-t pgsql11)
INFO  -    -host        host of database, may contain port
INFO  -    -port        optional port if not default
INFO  -    -db          database name
...
```

Comment: Could you add backticks around the executable statements, it makes the comment more readable and easier to execute the commands.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a few points.

1. You would be using Schema Spy with Graphviz. Versions 2.31+ does not add an entry to Window's System path variable.
   So after you download and install Graphviz  update the path variable to have path till Graphviz's bin directory.
   (C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.38\bin)
2. Alternative to downloading entire project source to change the classpath in the property file would be to update the jar using 7-zip.
3. Open the jar file using 7-zip  navigate to **net/sourceforge/schemaspy/dbTypes/**
   right click pgsql.properties say edit.
4. Change the following entry for driverPath to make it point to jdbc jar file
   **driverPath=D:/Work/JavaProjects/tools/postgresql-9.3-1100.jdbc4.jar**
5. Click on save and update. This should do the trick.